# How create a pixel selection tool? (Rect, Ellipse, Lasso options)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on a program that get the RGB values for an image and I'm planning to do some processing on the information.

In the programming I'm using Image to show the picture in XAML and bitmapimage and writeablebitmap to extract the RGBA values per pixel in a byte array.

I managed to do that, so my focus now is how to select the pixels i want to process in the image and for I need to create selection tools. Since it's dealing with images, I would need rect and ellipse as a minimum, Lasso as an extra to draw a selection path then place in an array the enclosed coordinates (which i'll match up to the byte values).

I have been looking over the net trying to find the best way to do this but the information is confusing. The headlines I found were:

- Image.clip, path geometry, path figure (skeleton solution)
  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/da61e706-5e03-44d3-8492-aaaee43c8970/how-to-make-a-selection-tool-like-the-lasso-tool-in-c?forum=wpf
- InkCanvas (I guess they are referring to select mode but no details given)
  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/da61e706-5e03-44d3-8492-aaaee43c8970/how-to-make-a-selection-tool-like-the-lasso-tool-in-c?forum=wpf
- Using adorner layers (seems quite complex)
  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45432/Developing-a-MultiSelector
- Simple drag selection (done for a listbox, best lead so far)
  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148503/Simple-Drag-Selection-in-WPF

So as you can see many suggestions but none with images specifically and very different approaches so I wanted to see if I can get feedback on what is the most efficient technique to doing this.

How would you do this?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for something like [BitmapSource.CopyPixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.copypixels(v=vs.110).aspx) but while your question is a great one, it's really, really broad. It would probably be helpful to go check out some already made tools for things like an [eye dropper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/374887/Eye-Dropper-control-in-WPF) and other proj's using the lasso and other tools you're looking for to see how they've done it and improve/expand on them.

Comment: I did use copypixels to get the whole image RGB data so that's done. The question is what is the best way to build a rectangle or ellipse selection tool, for example for focusing on the sky part of the image or texture of a wall in the image instead of the whole image.